# Apache Hue only show ten entry from hbase database

Tags: hbase, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, hue

I use hbase to store some data from web. And I also use the apache Hue to visually view the content in the hbase. But **it only shows the first ten entries from the database.** I could not get it to show more. There is no next page button.

I know I can use API and terminal to interact with the hbase, but I like the convenience that Hue gives me.

I am using the Hue that comes with the Cloudera 4.7.1-1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47. Is is too old?

Anyone know how to let the Hue show the rest of the hbase database? The searching does not seems to work really well either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a

> +20

In the query box. More examples on http://gethue.com/the-web-ui-for-hbase-hbase-browser/

Comment: Thanks, I use *.domain +20  command in the query box. And it works!